# boto3 dynamodb update item with Expected value

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I want to update a item only if it exists. If I dont use the Expected value, the item is inserted if it doesnt exists.

```
dynamo.update_item(TableName=tableName, Expected={"myVar":{"Exists":True},{"Value":{"S":"myValue"}}}, Key={"myVar":"myValue"}, AttributeUpdates={"myVar":{"Action":"PUT", "Value":"myNewValue"}})
```

that gives me a sintaxis error. some help?

Answer (score 0):

this is my anwser:

```
dynamo.update_item(TableName=tableName, Expected={"myVar":{"Exists":True, "Value":myValue}}, Key={"myVar":myValue}, AttributeUpdates={"myVar":{"Action":"PUT", "Value":myNewValue}})
```

when the condition ist not true, an exception is raised: ConditionalCheckFailedException